# Stackoverflow Style Notifications in asp.net Ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, notification-bar

When you get a badge or aren't logged in to stack overflow there's a groovy little notification bar at the top of the page that lets you know there's something going on.

I know the SOflow team use JQuery, but I was wondering if anyone knew of an implementation of the same style of notification system in asp.net AJAX.

On a side note, what's the "official" name for this style of notification bar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like it to.
div tag with a fade.
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Walkthrough/UsingAnimations.aspx

Answer (score 8):

In this post ( http://www.pieterg.com/post/2010/05/24/ASPNET-and-Stackoverflow-Type-Notification-Bar.aspx ) Pieter Germishuys explains how to implement the functionality using Dmitri's Smirnov plugin ( http://www.dmitri.me/blog/notify-bar/ )

Really easy !

Comment: That link is broken.  Seems like his site is having issues.  The post appears here. http://www.pieterg.com/Post/Posts/2010/5