# I need a notification system in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, notifications

I have a web application which our customer use it all day. Some times, i need to stop or restart application. When I do it, some customers' work is interrupted and this makes them nervous.

I want to make a notification system that, appear on application and inform customers about shutting down of system.

How can I make a system like that?

Comment: Why don't you put a newsticker somewhere on the site? So you can make announcements and the users stay informed.

Comment: Whats the reason the application keeps needing shut down?

Comment: Some times we have to make some working which need system to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For notification you can use [stackoverflow-style-notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465/stackoverflow-style-notifications-in-asp-net-ajax)

You also can customize error page "HTTP Error 500-12 Application Restarting"

Comment: Your second advice worth think about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to go here is with AJAX. Make some kind of Polling system which would poll every 5 or so minutes for new 'messages' on the server. your C# would then check if there are new messages, return them to the AJAX and some jQuery could could display a box or a modal to alert the user something will happen soon.

On refreshing a page or going to a new page this ajax could then run too, not waiting for the timer to run out.

Comment: Thanks for reply Stefanvds. Your advises all good for me except polling system. When I stop the system, application will be down and messages on the server will be unaccassable. am I wrong?

Comment: In my idea, one would post the message some time before the restart. so that all users are notified before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service on your network but there is another simple way...
there is a dos command which shows a message on specified user's screen... but this is worst way if ur program is not running on a small network...
The command is `NET SEND` but its no more available in windows vista and seven...
Here is the refrence: http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/net-send-command/

Comment: By the way, the best solution is to use create a service to show messages from server (or maybe interact with users...)

Answer (score 0):

You would put a message on a common page (home or login) a while before the update.  Something like "At xxxxxpm this site will be down".

When the time comes you replace their access to the system (such as the login page) with a page stating its down, you'll have to wait.  You would either place the new message page with that of the same name as the login, or configure the server to redirect automatically. This is how the major banks manage it.